# Unable to run systemd service without password despite NOPASSWD in sudoers file

Tags: command-line, 22.04, sudo, password

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and added a custom service file for systemd. I want to start/stop it without entering a password.

I checked several posts here and on other StackExchange instances but nothing works so far.

I would like to start and stop this service without having to enter a password each time. For this, I added the following lines to the sudoers file using visudo:

```
christian  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now
christian  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start mc
```

However, when I try to run the systemctl command, it still prompts me for a password:

```
christian@server:~$ sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start mc
[sudo] password for christian:
```

What might I be doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I think that line in sudoers should be `christian ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:  /usr/bin/systemctl start mc` and the other line should be similarly modified as well to work.

Comment: Do you really need to run `mc` as a *system* service? Have you considered running it as a [systemd user service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User)? that shouldn't require elevated privileges.

Comment: @Raffa I copy pasted your suggestion (this: `christian ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:  /usr/bin/systemctl start mc`) and it still does not work. I tried running it and it still prompts for the password. I'll try it later if a restart of the machine does the trick.

Comment: @steeldriver good point. Here it would work, but on other instances I need to run them as root, so I'd like to get this to work first. Thanks for your suggestion.